# Open a URL in Chrome Canary as incognito

Tags: applescript, automator, google-chrome

I am currently using this Automator AppleScript to create a service to open a URL using Chrome Canary in incognito mode

```
on run {input}
    set theURL to input
    if application "Google Chrome Canary" is running then
        tell application "Google Chrome Canary" to make new window with properties {mode:"incognito"}
    else
        do shell script "open -a /Applications/Google\\ Chrome\\ Canary.app --args {URL:theURL} --incognito"
    end if

    tell application "Google Chrome Canary" to activate
end run
```

Google Chrome Canary will launch with a new window, but the URL does not load. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have Google Chrome Canary installed but I do have Google Chrome installed and because you've not shown how `on run {input}` is actually receiving its *input*, what I'm presenting is being done in AppleScript Editor however you should be able to translate it to your use with Google Chrome Canary in Automator.

The following AppleScript *code* examples do what it is you're trying to do albeit in Google Chrome not Google Chrome Canary however change instances of Google Chrome to Google Chrome Canary as applicable and it should work as the examples do work as tested.

This first example uses the `do shell script` *command* in the `else` *block*:

```
set theURL to "http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270413/open-a-url-in-chrome-canary-as-incognito"

if application "Google Chrome" is running then
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate
        make new window with properties {mode:"incognito"}
        open location theURL
    end tell
else
    do shell script "open -a 'Google Chrome' --args --incognito " & quoted form of theURL
end if

tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
```

**Note:** When used in a Run AppleScript *action* in Automator you may not need to use `quoted form of` with `theURL`, so the last part of the `do shell script` *command* will in that case just be:
 `& theURL`

---

This second example forgoes the use of the `do shell script` *command* in the `else` *block*:

```
set theURL to "http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270413/open-a-url-in-chrome-canary-as-incognito"

if application "Google Chrome" is running then
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate
        make new window with properties {mode:"incognito"}
        open location theURL
    end tell
else
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate
        -- close window 1   # Uncomment this line if you want the normal window that opens first to be closed.
        make new window with properties {mode:"incognito"}
        open location theURL
    end tell
end if
```

Comment: When I use this solution, the url is opened in the original window, not the new incognito window.   Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @samspot, This answer is two and a half years old and what worked then in the current release of Google Chrome at that time may no longer be applicable to the current release today. What just worked for me with the latest version of Google Chrome today was to change `open location theURL` to `set URL of active tab of front window to theURL` so give that a try and let me know.

Comment: Thank you, that totally worked! I had tried something similar but was finding so many subtle versions that didn't work and couldn't work through it.  I really appreciate you answering my comment!